# Kio estas la indikilo de ŝanĝo de aktualaĵo en Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

La Angla havas "Now," kaj "Next," por indiki novan aktualaĵon. Ekzemple, jen ĉi tiuj:

"*Next*, we move on to logarithms."

aŭ (de la ekspoziciaĵo de John Oliver)

"*And now*, this."

Kiel oni diras tiujn frazojn Esperante?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mi dirus *sekve*.

Ekzemple:

> Sekve, ni daŭrigos al logaritmoj.

Por via dua ekzemplo mi proponas ĉi tion:

> Kaj nun, jen ĉi tio